# Setting Background Drawable to Button in xml does not change the color Android Studio 4.2 preview

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been doing this for years with no problem, when I need to create a button with curved corners I create a drawable with corners and a color and I use it as the background to the button I need to change, but since Android Studio 4.2 preview, it's not working any more. Can anyone help. Thanks.

Here is an example of how the drawable xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#EFB70E" />
    <corners android:radius="12dp" />
</shape>
```

and I set that drawable as the background of my button.

Comment: Your problem is it does not set in preview or it does not set when app run or both of them?

Comment: @miladsalimi both

Comment: Share your button codes please

Comment: @MohammadElsayed Are you using material theme ?

Comment: @DrHowdyDoo yes, do I need to change it?

Comment: @miladsalimi nothing special at all, just a button with background is set to the shape file above, may be because I am using material theme as DrHowdyDoo said

Comment: No, material design is good, there is a much better way to make your buttons round in material design by using styles. and one more thing all buttons in mdc have a default tint, you have to set it to none otherwise the button will be blue no matter what color u use.

Comment: Here have a look : [Buttons - Material Design](https://material.io/components/buttons/android#using-buttons)

Comment: I have explained the whole thing in my answer. hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Material Design components, buttons have a default backgroundTint value set to colorPrimary that is why no matter what color you use in your button's background, it will be tinted blue(colorPrimary).

Just Add this line in the button's code : `app:backgroundTint="@null"`

And a better way to make your buttons round in material design:

In your themes.xml file add this :

```
<style name="ShapeAppearance.App.SmallComponent" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.SmallComponent">
   <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
   <item name="cornerSize">8dp</item>
</style>


<style name="Widget.App.Button" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
   <item name="shapeAppearance">@style/ShapeAppearance.App.SmallComponent</item>
</style>
```

Then if you want to apply round corners to all buttons in the app, add this line in your app's main theme :

```
<item name="shapeAppearanceSmallComponent">@style/ShapeAppearance.App.SmallComponent</item>
```

Otherwise, if you want to apply this style to specific button, add this line to it's code:

```
style="@style/Widget.App.Button"
```

Comment: Thanks for solution